# BIRT change page numbers

Tags: birt, knime

Hi I am using BIRT with KNIME.

I am trying to set the starting page number based on a simple logic and then continue from there.

Essentially the logic for page number one would be variable_starting_page_number + pageNumber.

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Thank you in advance.